# How to set Twitter callback to obb?

Tags: twitter, callback

I have such code:

```
consumer = oauth2.Consumer (constants.consKey, constants.consSecret)
client = oauth2.Client (consumer)

response, content = client.request(constants.requestUrl, 'POST')

requestToken = dict (urlparse.parse_qsl (content.decode ('utf-8')))

print ('Enter the site:')
print ('{}?oauth_token={}'.format(constants.authUrl, requestToken ['oauth_token']))
```

How can I enable PIN authorization in a Twitter app?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
This must be put in the third code line when requested:

```
body=urlparse.urlencode({'oauth_callback':'oob'})
```

So the third code line must look like:

```
response, content = client.request(constants.requestUrl, 'POST', body=urlparse.urlencode({'oauth_callback':'oob'}))
```